# Examples of functions where $f(ab)=f(a)+f(b)$

Tags: functional-equations

What are some examples of continuous (on a certain interval) real or complex functions where $f(ab)=f(a)+f(b)$ (like $\ln x$?)

Comment: What if we drop the condition of continuity, and we fix the domain and range $\mathbb N \cup {0}$ ??

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Define $g(x)=f(e^x)$. Then 
$$g(x+y)=f(e^{x+y})=f(e^xe^y)=f(e^x)+f(e^y)=g(x)+g(y).$$

If $f$ is continuous, so is $g$, and it's a well-known exercise to show that $g$ must then be of the form $g(x)=cx$ for some constant $c$ (see [Cauchy's functional equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation)).

Thus, $\ln(x)$ and constant multiples of it are the only examples of the kind you seek.