# Is the product rule for logarithms an if-and-only-if statement?

Tags: logarithms, functional-equations

If a function $f(x)$ is proportional to $\ln x$, then we know
$$ f(xy) = f(x) + f(y). $$

My question is, is the converse true? If we know that, for an unknown function *f*,
$$ f(xy) = f(x) + f(y), $$
can we conclude that the function must be proportional to $\ln x$? Why?

Comment: Put $g(x)=f(e^x)$ and read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation).

Comment: Hi. Does the function $f$ continuous?

Comment: @Pp.. Much obliged. Plus I learned about an interesting new class of pathological functions!

Comment: @Farhad, no, it is not explicitly stated to be so. But I deduce from Pp..'s linked article that a sufficient condition on *f(x)* for the logarithmic solution to be unique is that it be continuous *at a single point* (or monotonic over *any interval* or bounded over *any interval*). Given the context in which the question arose, I feel alright excluding any functions pathological enough not to meet any of those conditions.

Comment: In [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/423492/overview-of-basic-facts-about-cauchy-functional-equation) you can find a few links some related equations. [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98673/examples-of-functions-where-fab-fafb) asks about continuous solutions of your (or Cauchy's) equation.